# Привязка цвета WPF Xaml из TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, дизайн

И так..условно у меня есть Color и ColorBrush:

```
<Color x:Key="clrPrimary">#6099f0</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryBrush" Color="{StaticResource clrPrimary}" />
```

И есть у меня Texbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<TextBox x:Name="colorBox" Margin="30,5,20,0"></TextBox>
```

Так вот, как сделать так чтобы после ввода значения в TextBox в формате HEX типа :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Автоматически менялось значение clrPrimary?

Comment: Значение ресурса — наверное никак, да и зачем вам это? Просто используйте привязки, возможно потребуется конвертер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, обратите, только внимание, что у меня DynamicResource в кисти:

```html
<Window.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="clrPrimary">#6099f0</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryBrush" Color="{DynamicResource clrPrimary}" />
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Background="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}">
    <TextBox x:Name="colorBox" Margin="5" TextChanged="colorBox_TextChanged" />
</StackPanel>
```

Обработчик:

```
private void colorBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var colorValue = Convert.ToInt64(((TextBox)sender).Text, 16);
    var color = (Color)this.Resources["clrPrimary"];
    color.R = (byte)(colorValue / 256 / 256);
    color.G = (byte)(colorValue / 256 % 256);
    color.B = (byte)(colorValue % 256 % 256);
    Resources["clrPrimary"] = color;
}
```

Вот так это работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]